# mean of two floating point numbers: why $a+\frac{b-a}{2}$ is better than $\frac{a+b}{2}$?

Tags: numerical-methods, floating-point

$a$ and $b$ are the floating point representation of two real numbers with no constraints (they can be both negative or both positive or one positive and the other negative and so on).

I read in the [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) [codebase](https://gitlab.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code/-/blob/9.900.x/include/armadillo_bits/op_mean_meat.hpp#L692), a linear algebra library, that the "robust" mean of the two  $a$ and $b$ is computed as $a+\frac{b-a}{2}$ and not as the (naïve) $\frac{a+b}{2}$.

I imagine that it is more robust for what regard the overflow that it can happen when $a$ and $b$ are similar to half the largest representable value; moreover I feel that if $a\approx b$ then the cancellation error incurring in their subtraction will not be a problem.

But, how one can rigorously prove these intuitions?

Comment: Are the numbers positive? Do we know that $a\leq b$?

Comment: @Arthur the linked code makes no assumptions about the sign of $a$ and $b$ and it does not compute the largest of the two.

Comment: It should be just to avoid exceeding `INT_MAX = 2147483647` (or any maximum integer allowed) when calculating `a+b`.

Comment: https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/2493882

Comment: @VIVID: But it is counter-productive in that regard if $a$ and $b$ have opposite signs.

Comment: If $a$, $b$ are of opposite signs, the robust mean makes the computation less robust ! (crossed with TonyK).

Comment: @TonyK Oh, good point :)

Comment: Then, to make it really robust `if-else` condition is needed to check if $ab>0$ or vice versa to choose the option

Comment: @VIVID: the post concerns floating-point numbers. The chances of avoiding overflow this way are much lower than for integer numbers. This even looks paranoid, unless there is a good reason.

Comment: Can you show instances of the use of this function ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust https://gitlab.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code/-/blob/9.900.x/include/armadillo_bits/op_median_meat.hpp#L380

Comment: This use case is for computation of the median, in the case of an even number of elements. It indeed keeps the computation overflow-free for any representable pairs of values (of the same sign) in the given type. For floating-point arguments, just paranoid. For bytes, quite useful :-)

Comment: A similar case can be found in the secant root formula central to many root finding methods. There it is also suggested to replace $\frac{af_b-bf_a}{f_b-f_a}$ by $a-f_a\frac{b-a}{f_b-f_a}$ to avoid difficulties in the limit where $a\approx b$, $f_a=f(a)\approx 0$. It seems similarly difficult to construct cases where this becomes visibly relevant.

Comment: @LutzLehmann do you have any reference to the suggestion you wrote about?

Comment: On second thought, in the first form one gets catastrophic cancellation in both numerator and denominator, the resulting quotient becomes inaccurate. While in the second form the catastrophic cancellation still may occur, the factor $f_a\approx 0$ makes the update small close to a root.

Comment: @LutzLehmann are you writing about the secant root formula?

Comment: Yes, it was relative to my first comment. For the original question, a more general case was extensively discussed in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/907327/accurate-floating-point-linear-interpolation

Comment: C++ [P0811r3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0811r3.html) states that $\frac{(a+b)}{2}$ can cause overflow, and that $a+\frac{(b-a)}{2}$ can cause overflow and produce incorrectly rounded results. $\frac{a}{2}+\frac{b}{2}$ prevents overflow but is not correctly rounded for subnormal inputs. It thus suggests switching between strategies: $\begin{cases}\frac{a}{2}+\frac{b}{2}&&\texttt{isnormal}(a)\,\texttt{&&}\,\texttt{isnormal}(b)\\\frac{a+b}{2}&&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.